# Local and production versions of php and mysql using git

Tags: php, mysql, database, git, dev-to-production

I have a question regarding how to set up local and production versions of a WordPress website that uses, PHP an MySQL.

I want to have these two versions (local and production) use different databases because we can test.

I will be using git to push my changes up to the server.

I have MySQL installed locally, and a webserver set up locally, but I don't know of a way to push mysql changes to the server and keep it connected with with git.

I will be working with several others so it needs to be using git for the database.

How would I go about doing this?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Usually you would use migrations and fixtures (eg. Doctrine), but you could stick a `mysqldump` into a git repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dump the scheme and/or the data to a file and then check that file into git.

For example, this will dump the table schema and data to a file named [table_name].sql

```
mysqldump --user=[user_name] -p --opt [local_database_name] [table_name] > [table_name].sql
```

To load this data in production, you would do something like this:

```
mysql --user=[user_name] -p [server_database_name] < [table_name].sql
```

Comment: Okay, so I call the first command to store the local version and save to a file, and then when I push, I push that file as well, and after that I have to load using second command on the server? That seems like one way I could do it. Is there a better way though?

Comment: There are some products dedicated to handling database version control, but I am not familiar with them. The approach I suggested is a method I know will work with git. Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: Thanks. This option seems feasible; its just that I thought it would be easier :P